# Ubuntu is there any frame by frame video editor software which can allow to place a picture?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-editor, editing

I have this video : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f8iOQ9zWP6A
Where i have to place two picture of my girl-friend, i have to replace the existing baby faces by those two pictures, which i will make a special DVD for one surprise / gift to my girl-friend. To make her smile.

But so far i have tried openShot but i can not edit frame by frame there. Then i tried Gimp with gimp-gap plugin, but still using Gimp is like i can spend 1 year to make this video.

Is there any frame by frame editing software available for Ubuntu? (for example, in Flash for Windows its easy to do such thing)

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may wish to give a chance to [**kdenlive**](http://www.kdenlive.org/), which includes several keyframable plugins like those you may need in order to do that work.

It comes to my mind the track plugin "MaskOMate" to "cut" the part of the image that you wish to put overlaying the video. Of course, it will be useful if you first prepare the images in order to fit the project's size, with transparency, then simply use the "Composite" track's transition in order to put the images over the video.

Both "MaskOMate" and "Composite" plugins are keyframable, so you can choose where to place your video elements in a certain moment of the video play.

See the official kdenlive site and the [Creative effects page](http://www.kdenlive.org/about-kdenlive/creative-effects) for further information.

In the next screenshot, I am using a pre-made transparency image with an amazed girl in order to place it on the background video where a man is appearing over a green screen wall. Of course, I also used the "Pan and Zoom" Plugin in order to make the image bigger. Remember: The best your sources are, the best results you'll get.

[image]

What you wish to achieve is complicated and a hard work but with patience and creativity you can create an awesome video.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. This tool  is much better then all the rest i yet used. Another option was also to use Blender where it allows to use Video editing frame by frame including scaling etc. But not so easy like this one.

Answer (score 0):

You could of course try with [LiVES](http://lives-video.com).

sudo apt-get install lives