# Is there a frame by frame video editor?

Tags: apt, software-recommendation, video

I have a video with text that I am trying to translate into other language, I will not place the translation as subtitles, the idea is to use the same font and place the translated text in the same place as the original text is.

The software that I need is a software that either let me do the previous (i.e. remove the text within the video) or that allows me to convert video frames to images (that I'd be able to edit with GIMP) and backwards (i.e. images to video) **AND** in both cases the software should allow me to introduce text in any coordinates of the video with any font I desire.

The software should also be able to "remove" any object from a video like Adobe After Effects as shown in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRFCq5mtx1s).

### Important note:

This question is not a duplicate of [Ubuntu is there any frame by frame video editor software which can allow to place a picture?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246406/ubuntu-is-there-any-frame-by-frame-video-editor-software-which-can-allow-to-plac) as this question asks for a different goal that was solved differently in the link provided.

Comment: I invite you to read carefully [this thread at meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/14014/177437) and then act accordingly: i) roll back this question to its initial version and ii) ask a different question with your new requirements.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa Done!, I am sorry, it will never happen again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have a frame by frame sequence of a video, the more elegant solution is to export all the sequence of frames once for all, instead of specific frames one by one.

In that case, the use of the `ffmpeg` package is required, as well as to convert the image sequence back to video.

### FFmpeg installation

In order to install `ffmpeg` the ppa should be added first. You can have deeper information about this in [Is FFmpeg missing from the official repositories in 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432542/is-ffmpeg-missing-from-the-official-repositories-in-14-04)

To add the ppa, open a terminal and run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
```

After that addition, in a terminal run the following to install FFmpeg:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

### Conversion from video to image sequence

Navigate with the terminal to the folder where you have the video and run:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -qscale 0 scene%05d.jpg
```

Note: the command `-qscale 0` is to keep the quality of the video in the images.

This images may be edited with the software of your preference: GIMP recommended.

### Conversion from image sequence to video

Once all the images edition have been done you can turn your images back to video by opening a terminal and running:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i scene%05d.jpg -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p newvideo.mp4
```

### A little plus

If you want to add sound to the video, the best way to do it is by installing a BASIC video editor, like: OpenShot(recommended), blender, cinelerra, kdenlive, etc.

Answer (score 3):

With [Avidemux](http://avidemux.org) (available from the Software Centre) you can:

- [Export frames as images](http://www.digital-photo-software-guide.com/avi-to-jpeg.html) - navigate to the frame you wish to convert and the then follow ***File*** > ***Save*** > ***Save JPEG image***.
- [Build a video from a series of images](http://avidemux.org/smif/index.php?topic=6035.0) - name the files as `0001.jpg`, `0002.jpg`,  `0003.jpg`, etc and then open the first file.

Comment: I answered the original question. Now you changed it to avoid accepting this answer. Neat.

Comment: Luis, you are right, I am sorry. I just did not want to ask too many questions about the same subject.

Comment: Luis, also remember that here in AskUbuntu! we try to put the information within the answer, and try not to refer steps of procedures to outer links, as they may be down in a moment. Links can be provided to another questions/answers in AskUbuntu! or to videos.

Comment: Which part of "***File*** > ***Save*** > ***Save JPEG image***" you do not understand? You are certainly set to get loads of help acting this way.

Comment: Actually what I told you is regarding the "Building a video from series of images" changing the name of the images won't give me a video, will it? BTW very mature of you to downvote my question and answer just because I did not choose yours. I solved in a different way, I am the OP so I have the right to choose the answer I want or create one my own. Now that you downvoted both my question and answer: explain why you downvoted, if you don't, we will have to escalate the situation.